# Relocation of data from flash to RAM during boot phase

Tags: c, flash, linker, boot, riscv

I'm currently trying to solve a problem which requires moving data from flash to RAM during the booting phase. Right now everything is only being simulated using a microcontroller architecture which is based on the open-source [PULPissimo](https://github.com/pulp-platform/pulpissimo). For simulation I use QuestaSim by Mentor Graphics. Toolchain is GNU.

Unfortunately I have pretty much zero experience on how to relocate data during the boot phase so I've read some posts and tutorials on this topic but I'm still confused about quite a few thing.

The situation is as follows: I set my boot mode to boot from flash which in this case means that the code will already reside pre-loaded inside the flash memory. The code is just a simply hello world or any other program really. When I simulate everything is compiled and the modules are loaded. After the boot phase the output "hello world" is displayed and the simulation is done. This means everything works as intended which is obviously a good sign and a good starting point.

Side note: As far as i know the PULPissimo architecture does not support direct boot from flash at the moment so the data from flash has to be moved to RAM (which they call L2) and executed.

From what I understand there are multiple things involved in the booting process. Please correct me if anything in the next paragraph is wrong:

First: The code that will be executed. It's written in C and has to be translated into a language which the architecture understands. This should be done automatically and reside in the flash memory pre boot phase. Considering that the code is actually being executed as mentioned above there is not much confusion here.

Second: The bootloader. This is also written in C. It is also translated and will be burned into ROM later on so changing this wouldn't make much sense. It loads the data which is neccessary for booting. It can also differentiate if you want to boot from flash or JTAG.

Third: The main startup file crt0.S. This is one of the things that confuse me, especially what it exactly does and what the difference between the bootloader and the main startup file is. Wikipedia (yes i know...) defines it as: "crt0 (also known as c0) is a set of execution startup routines linked into a C program that performs any initialization work required before calling the program's main function." So does that mean that it has noting to do with the boot phase but instead kind of "initializes" and/or loads only the code that I want to execute?

Fourth: The linker script link.ld. Even tho this is the part I read the most about, there are still quite a lot of questions. From what I understand the linker script contains information on where to relocate data. The data that is to be relocated is the data of the code i want to execute(?). It consists of different parts explained [here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/REGION_005fALIAS.html#REGION_005fALIAS).

```
.text program code;
.rodata read-only data;
.data read-write initialized data;
.bss read-write zero initialized data.
```

Sometimes I see more than those sections, not just text, rodata, data, bss. But how does the linker script know what the "text" is and what the "data" is and so on?

I know that's quite a lot and probably pretty basic stuff for a lot of you but I'm genuinely confused.

What I am trying to accomplish is relocating data from flash to RAM during the boot phase. Not only the code that I want to execute but more data that is also located in the flash memory. Consider the following simple scenario: I want to run a hello world C program. I want to boot from flash. Up to this point nothing special and everything works fine. Now after the data of the code I also load more data into flash, let's say 256 bytes of A (hex) so I can check my memory in QuestaSim by looking for AAAAAAAA sections. I also want to say where I want that data to be loaded during boot phase, for example 0x1C002000. I tried playing around with the crt0.S and the linker.ld files but with no success. The only time it actually worked was when I modified the bootloader.c file but I have to assume that this is already burned into ROM and i can't do any modifications on it. To be honest I'm not even sure if what I'm trying to do is even possible without any changes to the bootloader.c.

Thank you for your time.

---

**Update**

---

So I was playing around a bit and tried to create a simple example to understand what's happening and what manipulations or relocations I can do.
First I created a C file which basically contains only data.
Lets call it *my_test_data.c*

```
  int normal_arr[] = {0x55555555, 0x55555555, 0x55555555, 0x55555555, 0x55555555, 0x55555555, 0x55555555, 0x55555555};

  int attribute_arr[] __attribute__ ((section(".my_test_section"))) = {0x66666666, 0x66666666, 0x66666666, 0x66666666, 0x66666666, 0x66666666, 0x66666666, 0x66666666};

  static int static_arr[] = {0x77777777, 0x77777777, 0x77777777, 0x77777777, 0x77777777, 0x77777777, 0x77777777, 0x77777777};

  int normal_var = 0xCCCCCCCC;

  static int static_var = 0xDDDDDDDD;

  int result_var;
```

Then I created the object file. I looked into it via objdump and could see my section *my_test_section* :

```
  4 .my_test_section 00000020  00000000  00000000  00000054  2**2
```

After that I tried to modify my linker script so that this section would be loaded to an address that I specified. These are the lines I added in the linker script (probably more than needed). It is not the whole linker script!:

```
CUT01       : ORIGIN = 0x1c020000, LENGTH = 0x1000
```

```
     .my_test_section : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*(.my_test_section))
        _smytest = .;
        *(.my_test_section)
        *(.my_test_section.*)
        _endmytest = .;
     } > CUT01
```

I wanted to see what data from *my_test_data.c* gets moved and where it gets moved. Remember that my goal is to have the data inside the RAM (Addr.: 0x1c020000) after booting (or during booting however you prefer). Unfortunately only:

```
int normal_arr[] = {0x55555555, 0x55555555, 0x55555555, 0x55555555, 0x55555555, 0x55555555, 0x55555555, 0x55555555};
```

gets moved into ROM (Addr.: 0x1A000000) as it seems to be part of the .text section (iirc) which is already being handled by the linker script:

```
    .text : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*(.vectors))
        _stext = .;
        *(.text)
        *(.text.*)
        _etext  =  .;
        *(.lit)
        ( ... more entries ...)
        _endtext = .;
    }  > ROM
```

What also confuses me is the fact that I can add this line in the above .text section:

```
         *(.my_test_section)
```

and then the data from the attribute_arr will be located in ROM but if I try to move it to the address I added (CUT01) nothing will ever end up there.

I also generated the map file which also lists *my_test_section*. This is an excerpt from the map file (don't mind the locations of where the output files are on my machine).

```
.my_test_section
                0x000000001c020000       0x3c
                0x000000001c020000                _mts_start = .
 *(.text)
 *(.text.*)
 *(.comment)
 .comment       0x000000001c020000       0x1a /.../bootloader.o
                                         0x1b (size before relaxing)
 .comment       0x000000001c02001a       0x1b /.../my_test_data.o
 *(.comment.*)
 *(.rodata)
 *(.rodata.*)
 *(.data)
 *(.data.*)
 *(.my_test_section)
 *fill*         0x000000001c02001a        0x2 
 .my_test_section
                0x000000001c02001c       0x20 /.../my_test_data.o
                0x000000001c02001c                attribute_arr
 *(.my_test_section.*)
 *(.bss)
 *(.bss.*)
 *(.sbss)
 *(.sbss.*)
                0x000000001c02003c                . = ALIGN (0x4)
                0x000000001c02003c                _mts_end = .
OUTPUT(/.../bootloader elf32-littleriscv)
```

I will continue to try to get this to work but right now I'm kind of confused as to why it seems like *my_test_section* gets recognized but not moved to the location which I specified. This makes me wonder if I made a mistake (or several mistakes) in the linker script or if one of the other files (bootloader.c or crt0.S) might be the reason.

Comment: I am not familiar with your environment, but, depending on the environment, the loader, etc., I have done things like this just through the program configuration and loader file, and I've had to do it with a loop in assembler which was executed before main() -- that was code, not data; all the data was initialized dynamically by the code and none was loaded!  So a little hard to give a general answer :-)

Comment: That said, this is probably not the primitive environment I described above.  As a guideline, data defined as const is usually kept in read only memory.  Data in the bss segment is uninitialized -- variables but no stored data.  the .data section has initialized static (including global, shhhhh...) variables -- in a system which is not unusually primitive this data should be loaded into RAM when the program begins.

Comment: I think you are trying to ask several questions at once.  Perhaps if you break it down, the questions will be easier to answer.  For example, you ask about crt0 and whether it is connected to the boot phase or not.  You ask "But how does the linker script know what the "text" is and what the "data" is and so on?" etc.

Comment: You are right about it being several questions at once but I thought it would maybe make sense as they seem to be closely related to each other. Let me start by focusing on the crt0.S. The quote says: "crt0 is a set of execution startup routines linked into a C program that performs any initialization work required before calling the program's main function." Can it still be used to relocate data (besides the program itself) from flash to RAM? Data that is not used by the program itself? Or does the additional data have to be included in some way, e.g. as a header? Because that's my main goal.

Comment: crt0 is not something you usually write.  It is usually part of the standard C library (and not written in C)  Why do you want to move data that is not used by the program?  Who/what is going to use it?

Comment: I'm also not sure why you feel that the bootloader can't be customized.  I've worked on firmware projects with custom bootloaders.   A custom bootloader should be written once and  not generally upgraded, although in some setups it should be possible to do so.  Possible does not always mean recommended though.

Comment: The additional data that I want to move is used by an accelerator. The problem being that if I would have that data inside the C code I want to execute it would be too large for the RAM memory segment where the image is being placed. But I'm thinking that maybe it could still be possible to do this and declare that data as something (similar to .text or .data) to move it to a different segment by modifying the linker script. I am currently reading into that to see if it's possible. I know that it can be done by modifying the bootloader but right now we assume that the bootloader if fixed.

Comment: I still don't understand why this can't be in the .data section. That is not the segment with the code...it is for data.  It should be possible to increase the RAM available to the .data section, via the linker file.  Or to create a custom section and put it where you want to in memory, with some kind of #pragma to put certain data there.

Comment: Maybe you can show the sections part of your linker script?

Comment: First of all I want to thank you for your help and information. I'm currently watching a lecture on bare metal embedded and it's really interesting. I will try to get everything to work the way I want to. The only thing that worries me is if I put the additional data inside the code that there might be some other data actually needed by the code itself that might get relocated too. Anyway I'll try to get this to work and will update this thread if I get stuck at some point. I feel like this is the best way for me to learn about this topic.

Comment: OK.  Good luck!  When you have learned from a lecture, you'll probably be able to define more focused questions (if you still have any), so feel free to come back and ask.

Comment: I have updated my original post with my current status. I feel like this helps to make things stay clear and readable.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your section definition, with a long list of sections inside it -- which are probably defined elsewhere in the linker script....what are you trying to do in this section?  If I understood that, I might have a suggestion...

Comment: Also, you mentioned that normal_array is copied to ROM, but you gave what looks (in the context of your question) like a RAM address.  Did you mean, copied to RAM?

Comment: Well I tried to see what happens so there might be unnecessary sections inside the definition and I have already removed most of them by now. What I am trying to do: Have my data associated with its own section like I did with ".my_test_section" on the "attribute_arr". This way I want to tell the linker script to load that data at specific addresses.

The unmodified linker script has 2 entries in the Memory section:

ROM         : ORIGIN = 0x1A000000, LENGTH = 0x2000

L2             : ORIGIN = 0x1C000000, LENGTH = 0x4000

Comment: Do you just want all the read/write data moved to your specified address, or specific variables?

Comment: I want to keep the existing relocation of boot related data and programm related data. I try to add rules for relocating additional data. At the end I want to have four files which basically only contain data, each with its own attribute (like I did in the "my_test_data.c" file). The linker script should define to move all data from "my_test_data1.c" (or more like from the generated output file) to address A and all data from "my_test_data2.c" to address B and so on. This is read only data. It should reside in RAM at the given addresses after booting. That's pretty much all I'm trying to do.

Comment: Why do you want to move read only data to RAM? For speed?  Because if you can keep it in flash, it is far less likely to be corrupted.

Comment: It looks as though it is setting up the section but not copying the data.  You may have to add code to do that, either in the loader, or at the very beginning of main (the very beginning of main is probably better; after all the automatic loading is done but before you start any of the real work of the program.

Comment: I have already created hardware and code that loads that additional data from L2 into an accelerator.
The flash memory isn't memory mapped from I have been told so I have to pass a valid L2 address to the accelerator which then starts loading the data from that L2 address. I'm going to double check but from what I have been told I have to move my data to L2 first. As I said the "normal_arr"gets loaded into ROM as it is part of the .data section (the map file verifies this). But the "attribute_arr" is not loaded at 0x1C020000 even tho the map file lists it with the same size of 36 Byte.

Comment: The only difference I see in the map file is the following: The "normal_arr" is listed under _.data.normal_arr_ while the "attribute_arr" is only listed under _.my_test_section_ but I'm not sure if this is the problem somehow...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216044/discussion-between-basya-and-laha).

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot being asked here.  I'm going to take a stab at answering part of the questions.  you ask:

> But how does the linker script know what the "text" is and what the
>   "data" is and so on?

The additional, custom, sections, and the predefined sections, are handled differently.
Custom sections usually require the related variables to have the section specified with a pragma.
The standard sections are defined by their type:

**text:** this is the code. that should be clear; the instructions to the computer of what to do, not the data

**rodata:** const data -- such as literal strings (eg. `"This is a literal string"` in the code.  A good compiler/linker should put variables defined as 'const' (not const parameters) in the rodata section as well.

**bss:**  static or global variables which are not initialized when declared:

```
int global_var_not_a_good_idea; // not in a function; local variables are different
static int anUninitializedArray[10];
```

**data:**   static or global variables which are initialized when declared

```
int initializedGlobalVarStillNotRecommended = 10;
static int initializedArray[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

This data should be copied to RAM when the program loads.

EDIT:
Somewhere in your startup code should be a reset handler.  This function will be called on processor reset.  It should be the function that copies data to RAM, possibly clears the zero segment, initializes the C library, etc.  When finished with initializations, it should call main();

Here is an example (in this case, from generated or example code for the Atmel SAMG55 processor, but the idea should be the same) of relocating data to RAM.
In the linker script memory space definitions  (I'm going to leave out the real numbers):
  ram (rwx)             : ORIGIN = 0x########, LENGTH = 0x########

in the linker script section definitions:
    .relocate : AT (_etext)
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _srelocate = .;
        *(.ramfunc .ramfunc.*);
        *(.data .data.*);
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _erelocate = .;
    } > ram

note that _etext is the end of the previous section

_srelocate and _erelocate are used in the startup code to relocate, I believe, everything in .data (and, apparently, .ramfunc as well) in all the files:

/* Initialize the relocate segment */
    pSrc = &_etext;
    pDest = &_srelocate;

```
if (pSrc != pDest) {
        for (; pDest < &_erelocate;) {
                *pDest++ = *pSrc++;
        }
}
```

This is a pretty standard example.  If you search in your project for where main() is called, you should find something similar.

If all you want to do is relocate the entire .data section to the address you are specifying in RAM, you should need only to change the definition of the location of the RAM section, not define your own.  You only need to define your own section if you want to move *specific variables* to a different location

I am not familiar with the platform on which you are working, but there should be either a C or assembly file with the startup code that runs *before* crt0.  This will set up the stack, heap, and interrupt vectors.  In some implementations, this code also copies the .data section to RAM, and may be set up to copy everything from the beginning of the data section until the beginning of the .bss section, to RAM. If your platform is set up in this way, if you locate your section between .data and .bss, it should be copied with no other changes from you (see [here](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2019/04/17/exploring-startup-implementations-newlib-arm/), for example).

If, however, you want to copy the data to a different location, you will probably have to add code to copy it, either in the loader code or at the very beginning of main, using the symbols you defined for the beginning and ending of the section.

Since you mention, though, that it is read-only data, I would recommend leaving it in read-only memory if you can.